# Explanation of a factoring process

Tags: factoring

I have found in a solved exercise the following:

$$x^{-2}-\sqrt{2}x^{-1}+1=(1-e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot x^{-1})(1-e^{-j\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot x^{-1})$$

Can someone explain how did the exponentials appear and how they end up being multiplied with $x^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u=x^{-1}$ and solve the quadratic equation $u^2-\sqrt2u+1=0$: $\Delta=-2$, so the roots are:
$$z_1,z_2=\frac{\sqrt 2\pm \mathrm i\sqrt2}2=\mathrm e^{\pm\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4},$$
whence the factorisation
$$u^2-\sqrt2u+1=\Bigl(u-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}\Bigr)\Bigl(u-\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}\Bigr).$$
Then replace $u$ with $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you but what I can't understand is how do we get $1-e^{j \pi/4}\cdot x^{-1}$?

Comment: Factor out $\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}$ in the first factor, $\,\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}$ in the second.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer,

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+j)=e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}}$$